# How to set docker run arguments on marathon spec

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have been using docker to run images along with some options like:

```
docker run --net host --oom-kill-disable -d -p <port>:<port> image
```

How do I set values like --oom-kill-disable on marathon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is required for docker containers in their marathon spec to specify a boolean value for oom-kill-disable flag for executor to run properly.

So the spec would include:

```
"parameters": [
            { "key": "oom-kill-disable", "value": "true" }
        ]
```

Comment: Just FYI, the same can also be applied to `--init` parameter. In case someone is using the mesos java API, here is an example `Protos.ContainerInfo.DockerInfo.newBuilder().addParameters(Protos.Parameter.newBuilder().setKey("init").setValue("true"))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if you can pass an empty value in this case, but you could go with something like this:

```
"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
        "network": "HOST",
        "image": "your/image",
        "parameters": [
            { "key": "oom-kill-disable", "value": "" }
        ]
    }
}
```

You may read a little bit more [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html) in "Privileged Mode and Arbitrary Docker Options" section.